# Manipulate a string containing a file's path to get only the file name

Tags: javascript, string

I got a file path as

> falsefile:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D4B6F6CD-5E5C-4459-90CC-0C649B3B31B8/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540hherax%252Fiia-mas-app-new//IIAMASATTCHMENTS/BD6FE729-70F1-48B0-83EB-8E7D956E599E.MOV

as file extension will change as file type
file path will also  change

how could I manipulate string to get file name as

```
BD6FE729-70F1-48B0-83EB-8E7D956E599E"
```

is in given example

2nd example of path and file type change

> falsefile:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D4B6F6CD-5E5C-4459-90CC-0C649B3B31B8/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540ppphrx%252Fiia-mas-app-new//IIAMASATTCHMENTS/DD6FE729-60F2-58B0-8M8B-8E759R6E547K.jpeg

Comment: `yourPath.split("/").pop().split(".").shift()`

Comment: Epitaph asked: You can use RegExp object for this, but at first you need to find the pattern, this part of path (IIAMASATTCHMENTS/) is constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do simply

```js
  let str="falsefile:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D4B6F6CD-5E5C-4459-90CC-0C649B3B31B8/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540hherax%252Fiia-mas-app-new//IIAMASATTCHMENTS/BD6FE729-70F1-48B0-83EB-8E7D956E599E.MOV"


console.log(  str.split(".")[0].split("/").pop()
)
```

just remember split split pop

Answer (score 0):

Some variation of slice/split would work

```js
const str = 'falsefile:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D4B6F6CD-5E5C-4459-90CC-0C649B3B31B8/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540hherax%252Fiia-mas-app-new//IIAMASATTCHMENTS/BD6FE729-70F1-48B0-83EB-8E7D956E599E.MOV'

console.log(
  str.slice(str.lastIndexOf("/")+1).split(".")[0]
)
// or

console.log(
  str.split("/").pop().split(".")[0]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression for example.
The first thing comes in my mind is:

```js
const filepath = 'falsefile:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D4B6F6CD-5E5C-4459-90CC-0C649B3B31B8/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540hherax%252Fiia-mas-app-new//IIAMASATTCHMENTS/BD6FE729-70F1-48B0-83EB-8E7D956E599E.MOV'
const filenameWithoutExtension = filepath.match(/IIAMASATTCHMENTS\/(.*)\./)[1] // "BD6FE729-70F1-48B0-83EB-8E7D956E599E"

console.log(filenameWithoutExtension)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions like here:

```js
function get_filename(str) {
  const regex = /\/([A-Z0-9\-_]+)\.[\w\d]+/gm;
  let m = regex.exec(str);
  return m[1];
}
console.log(
  get_filename(`falsefile:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D4B6F6CD-5E5C-4459-90CC-0C649B3B31B8/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540ppphrx%252Fiia-mas-app-new//IIAMASATTCHMENTS/DD6FE729-60F2-58B0-8M8B-8E759R6E547K.jpeg`)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "falsefile:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D4B6F6CD-5E5C-4459-90CC-0C649B3B31B8/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540hherax%252Fiia-mas-app-new//IIAMASATTCHMENTS/BD6FE729-70F1-48B0-83EB-8E7D956E599E.MOV",
  re = /[\w|-]*\.\w*/
stringNameWithExt = str.match(re)
stringNameWithoutExt = str.match(re)[0].split(".")[0]
console.log(stringNameWithoutExt)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var filpath = "falsefile:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D4B6F6CD-5E5C-4459-90CC-0C649B3B31B8/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540hherax%252Fiia-mas-app-new//IIAMASATTCHMENTS/BD6FE729-70F1-48B0-83EB-8E7D956E599E.MOV"
console.log(
  filpath.substring(filpath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, filpath.length).substring(1, filpath.substring(filpath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, filpath.length).lastIndexOf('.'))
)
```

Comment: That is far to verbose. No need to add filpath.length to your substring statements

Answer (score 0):

If you know the format of the value you want to capture, you might get a more exact match using a regex and capture your value in the first capturing group.

You might use the `/i` flag to make the match case insensitive.

```
([A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+){4})\.\w+$
```

That will match:

- `(` Capturing group

  - `[A-Z0-9]+` Match 1+ times what is listed in the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
  - `(?:-[A-Z0-9]+){4}` Repeat 4 times matching a hyphen and 1+ times what is listed in the character class
- `)` Close capturing group
- `\.\w+$` Match a dot, 1+ times a word char and assert the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bo02pR/1)

```js
let strs = [
  `falsefile:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D4B6F6CD-5E5C-4459-90CC-0C649B3B31B8/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540hherax%252Fiia-mas-app-new//IIAMASATTCHMENTS/BD6FE729-70F1-48B0-83EB-8E7D956E599E.MOV`,
  `falsefile:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D4B6F6CD-5E5C-4459-90CC-0C649B3B31B8/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540ppphrx%252Fiia-mas-app-new//IIAMASATTCHMENTS/DD6FE729-60F2-58B0-8M8B-8E759R6E547K.jpeg`
];
let pattern = /([A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+){4})\.\w+$/i;
strs.forEach(str => console.log(str.match(pattern)[1]));
```